# How to name a file using a value in a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, filenames

For example I have a list inside a dictionary:

```
{'results': [{'name': 'sarah', 'age': '18'}]}
```

I want make a text file and the name of file must be the value of dict `'name'`
ex: `sarah.txt`.

How should I code it in python?

Comment: Did you try to write some code? If yes please post here with the issues that you faced in that code.

Comment: If the dictionary is `d`, then `d['results'][0]['name']` contains `'sarah'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
dictionary = {'results': [{'name': 'sarah', 'age': '18'}]}
name = dictionary['results'][0]['names'] + '.txt'
open(name, "w")
```

Opening a file in the `w`rite mode, if it doesn't exist already, will create a new file with that name.

Comment: and will truncate the file if it does exist.

Comment: Yes, although if he wanted, he could use the `a`ppending mode to add to an existing file.